# Leiningen does not create the STANDALONE jar file

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen

I have created a new project with

```
lein new app lern
```

which gives me this project.clj:

```
(defproject lern "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
               [seesaw "1.4.5"]]
:main ^:skip-aot lern.core
:target-path "target/%s"
:profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

I do have `(:gen-class)` in my `ns` decleration and a `(-main)` in my core.clj file. Now being in the project directory (lern) doing: `lein uberjar` doesn't create any jar file inside of my target directory. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What's in your main class?  Does core.clj compile?

Comment: I followed your steps and a file target/uberjar/lern-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar was created. What is the output when you run the command?